# Rails multiple registration paths with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, nested

I'm using devise in rails, and I'm trying to create a second registration path, the default registration path for users (which works perfectly), and a second registration path whereby a user registers and creates a project in a single action as a "Getting Started" action (Think Freelancer.com or any marketplace whereby non-users can register and create their first project in one action).

I've gone through so many threads but they all seem to want to replace the existing registration action. I want to keep the existing registration action and either add a `getting_started_new` and `getting_started_create` actions to the existing `User::Registration` controller, or create a new `GettingStarted` Controller with methods for `new` and `create` that would then allow the nested form (for a user and their new project).

My latest iteration looks something like this:

**routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users

resources :users do
  resources :projects
end

devise_scope :user do
  get "getting_started" =>'getting_started#new'
  post "getting_started" =>'getting_started#create'
end
```

**getting_started_controller.rb**

```
class GettingStartedController < Devise::RegistrationsController

def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.projects.build  
end

def create
  @user = User.new(getting_started_params)
  redirect_to root, notice: "Done"
end

private
  def getting_started_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :phone, :password, :email, projects_attributes: [:user_id, :project_type_id, :name, :industry_id, :description, :budget_id, :project_status_id, feature_ids:[], addon_ids:[]])
  end

end
```

But when I try and actually submit the form, it loads the `get`action from the new controller, and the `post` action from the devise registration controller.

```
Started GET "/getting_started" for ::1 at 2016-10-17 09:15:58 +0200
Processing by GettingStartedController#new as HTML
Rendering getting_started/new.html.erb within layouts/application
Project_type Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "project_types".* FROM "project_types"
Industry Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "industries".* FROM "industries" ORDER BY "industries"."name" ASC
Feature Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "features".* FROM "features" ORDER BY "features"."name" ASC
Addon Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "addons".* FROM "addons"
Budget Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "budgets".* FROM "budgets"
Rendered getting_started/new.html.erb within layouts/application (32.9ms)
Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.9ms)
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 97ms (Views: 86.4ms | ActiveRecord: 2.9ms)


Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2016-10-17 09:16:54 +0200
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"hYrC/15zIF3DzPvhpFQH6LVS9H8XbhfHY1aRkgc2iX6Mdfvz33/O4p72XTpmY4X8E6B+dGfOmjZw7IoizvYwSA==", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"John", "last_name"=>"Smith", "phone"=>"0340239402309", "email"=>"test@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "project"=>{"name"=>"This is a test", "description"=>"Tester Description", "feature_ids"=>[""], "addon_ids"=>[""]}}, "project"=>{"project_type_id"=>"4", "industry_id"=>"2", "budget_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create account"}
Unpermitted parameter: project
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
SQL (1.5ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at", "first_name", "last_name", "phone") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "test@example.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$11$VEVjSrnc5Y5c8ofXvNmlMOHrS.v4tQuBoKMLdHaSOA2S6fiVIHfE."], ["created_at", 2016-10-17 07:16:55 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-10-17 07:16:55 UTC], ["first_name", "John"], ["last_name", "Smith"], ["phone", "0340239402309"]]
 (139.1ms)  COMMIT
 (0.1ms)  BEGIN
 SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "sign_in_count" = $1, "current_sign_in_at" = $2, "last_sign_in_at" = $3, "current_sign_in_ip" = $4, "last_sign_in_ip" = $5, "updated_at" = $6 WHERE "users"."id" = $7  [["sign_in_count", 1], ["current_sign_in_at", 2016-10-17 07:16:55 UTC], ["last_sign_in_at", 2016-10-17 07:16:55 UTC], ["current_sign_in_ip", "::1/128"], ["last_sign_in_ip", "::1/128"], ["updated_at", 2016-10-17 07:16:55 UTC], ["id", 17]]
 (0.3ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 319ms (ActiveRecord: 141.7ms)
```

I realise that devise does a whole bunch of other stuff besides simply recording the user data, so it may be better to rather move these actions to the Devise `User::RegistrationController`, and then tweak the accepted params. But how do you override Devise so that it doesn't auto use the devise `create` method the second you click the submit button, and would instead use a `getting_started_create` action?

Comment: post the form in `getting_started#new`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First off `getting started` is a pretty horrible name for a controller since it is not a noun. You can't say *a getting started*. So lets change it to *QuickstartsController*.

Lets setup the routes for this resource:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # These are your "normal" devise routes
  devise_for :users

  # This is the mapping for the "quickstart" routes
  devise_for :quickstarts,
    class_name: 'User',
    only: [],
    controllers: { registrations: 'quickstarts' }

  # These are the actual routes for quickstarts
  devise_scope :quickstart do
    get   "/quickstarts/new", to: "quickstarts#new", as: :new_quickstart
    post  "/quickstarts",    to: "quickstarts#create", as: :quickstarts
  end
end
```

Whenever you are overriding a library controller it is important to take some time to study how [the class you are superclassing](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/83d5d3142d57273603149046cfd0d1ef0d89dd59/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb) actually works.

If you look at the Devise controllers almost all the actions have a line like:

```
yield resource if block_given?
```

Which lets you tap into the flow of the original implementation by calling `super` with a block:

```
class QuickstartsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  # GET /quickstarts/new
  def new
    # This block is passed to the super class implementation:
    super do |resource|
      resource.projects.build
    end
  end

  # POST /quickstarts
  def create
    # You can pass a block here too if you want.
    super
  end

  private

  # This should redirect to the newly created project
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    polymorphic_path( resource.projects.last )
  end

  # This is the method Devise devise calls for the params.
  def sign_up_params
    # Don't write your params sanitiation on one line! Its not cool.
    params.require(:user)
          .permit(
              :first_name, :last_name, :phone, :password, :email,
              projects_attributes: [
                 :user_id, :project_type_id, :name,
                 :industry_id, :description, :budget_id,
                 :project_status_id,
                 feature_ids:[],
                 addon_ids:[]
              ]
          )
  end
end
```

> But how do you override Devise so that it doesn't auto use the devise
>   create method the second you click the submit button, and would
>   instead use a getting_started_create action?

Point the form to the correct controller - by passing the `url` option to `form_for`.

*app/views/quickstarts/new.html.erb:*

```
<h2>Getting Started</h2>

<%= form_for( resource, as: :user, url: quickstarts_path ) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Project</legend>
    <% f.fields_for :projects do |pf| %>
      <%# ... %>
    <% end %>
  </fieldset>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you, will give this a try this evening! Also noted on the name, makes sense - will also change to quickstart :)

Comment: Remember to have a look at the source for [Devise::RegistrationsController](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/83d5d3142d57273603149046cfd0d1ef0d89dd59/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb) if you run into trouble.

Comment: Thanks - makes so much more sense now - especially the `super` action! It's now calling all of the right controllers & actions, and is actually posting the info. However, I'm getting an error for `param is missing or the value is empty: user` when I click to submit. The actual param data that is submitting appears to be submitting as `quickstart =>` rather than `user =>`, which I think is causing the error? I included the controller under the /user folder for consistency and made updates to the class name and routes to account for the folder `user`.

Comment: Parameter shows as follows:{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"v22JbDbqTjvygxQ+N4K7q+eFHo3WlhSUBcSPcpLVGGk7pJrHx871VsQr0IiMfzyddeBOjH7/bqjW0zDVBy8uRw==",
 "quickstart"=>
  {"first_name"=>"test",
   "last_name"=>"exampler",
   "phone"=>"123123123",
   "email"=>"test@example.com",
   "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
   "projects"=>{"name"=>"adsadas", "description"=>"asds;adas;dkas;l", "feature_ids"=>["", "7"], "addon_ids"=>["", "1"]}},
 "project"=>{"project_type_id"=>"2", "industry_id"=>"25", "budget_id"=>"2"},
 "commit"=>"Sign up"}.

Comment: Try changing `as: resource_name` to `as: :user`. It should set the root key correctly.

Comment: `resource_name` is one of those crazy devise things where it tries to figure out the user class name based on the routes, the current faze of the moon and several other mysterious factors.

Comment: However when I spun an app to test it out I got "resource_name == 'user'`. Strange

Comment: Awesome, that worked :) But I'm now getting an 'unpermitted parameter: projects` error. I've been through the form, and it all looks sound. Even double checked the permit params in the controller, and it references `:projects`? It saves the user though, but doesn't save the project? Sorry for the hassle!

Comment: Did you add the project fields in` f.fields_for :projects` ? In that case they should be nested properly under `projects_attributes` - otherwise you can always ask a new question

Comment: Cheers thanks @max, yes they are. Think it may have to do with some of the drop downs and things that I have. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I eventually solved the issue with some form tweaking, and then got an error that there was no user. Added the inverse_of options set out in this article and it worked a treat! [link](https://www.viget.com/articles/exploring-the-inverse-of-option-on-rails-model-associations)